# Date stored in varchar format. Result issue

Tags: mysql, date

Sorry for my poor technical English. I try to get some data from my db between now with 1 month interval.

This query work perfectly (221 rows returns)

```
SELECT idEcare,reference 
FROM DEMS
WHERE (((etatSuivant ="Etat_ADM_131276535415392&SURF=Transmis") 
OR (etatSuivant = "Etat_ADM_121276535415390&SURF=Traitement en cours") 
OR (etatSuivant = "Etat_ADM_11276535415374&SURF=A l étude") 
OR (etatSuivant = "Etat_ADM_81276535415384&SURF=Programmé")) 
AND ((categorisation LIKE "%Propreté:Tas sauvage%") 
OR (categorisation LIKE "%Circulation et stationnement:Véhicule gênant%") 
OR (categorisation LIKE "%Circulation et stationnement:Véhicule ventouse_Epave_Brûlé%")
OR (categorisation LIKE "%Propreté:Passage ponctuel%") 
OR (categorisation LIKE "%Propreté:Corbeille pleine%") 
OR (categorisation LIKE "%Propreté:Huile_Verre cassé%") 
OR (categorisation LIKE "%Propreté:Désherbage_Feuilles mortes%") 
OR (categorisation LIKE "%Propreté%") 
OR (categorisation LIKE "%Espace Vert:Entretien des massifs:Nettoyage%") 
OR (categorisation LIKE "%Mobilier urbain:Corbeille:Réparation%")) 
AND (confidentialite = "Non"))
```

I want return the row from last month only. I have tried BETWEEN fonction but my  field "dateModification" is in VARCHAR format ( "06/02/2012 13:55:09") so i have a result : Truncated incorrect date value: "06/06/2016 13:55:09"

How i can modify this query to have a rows from the last 30 days only ?

Comment: Wow, learn about `IN()` and `REGEXP`

Comment: Hint: `str_to_date`.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Hi sagi, thanks for the tip but unfortunately i can't change this query because she's generated from software. I recover this query and seeks to show the records of the last 30 days

Comment: @SysDragon, how to show the records of the last 30 days. I've tried     SELECT idEcare,reference FROM DEMS WHERE dateModification BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND (((eta..... but i have an error : Truncated incorrect date value: "06/06/2016 13:55:09"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `STR_TO_DATE` function.

```
SELECT idEcare,reference 
FROM DEMS
WHERE (((etatSuivant ="Etat_ADM_131276535415392&SURF=Transmis") 
OR (etatSuivant = "Etat_ADM_121276535415390&SURF=Traitement en cours") 
OR (etatSuivant = "Etat_ADM_11276535415374&SURF=A l étude") 
OR (etatSuivant = "Etat_ADM_81276535415384&SURF=Programmé")) 
AND ((categorisation LIKE "%Propreté:Tas sauvage%") 
OR (categorisation LIKE "%Circulation et stationnement:Véhicule gênant%") 
OR (categorisation LIKE "%Circulation et stationnement:Véhicule ventouse_Epave_Brûlé%")
OR (categorisation LIKE "%Propreté:Passage ponctuel%") 
OR (categorisation LIKE "%Propreté:Corbeille pleine%") 
OR (categorisation LIKE "%Propreté:Huile_Verre cassé%") 
OR (categorisation LIKE "%Propreté:Désherbage_Feuilles mortes%") 
OR (categorisation LIKE "%Propreté%") 
OR (categorisation LIKE "%Espace Vert:Entretien des massifs:Nettoyage%") 
OR (categorisation LIKE "%Mobilier urbain:Corbeille:Réparation%")) 
AND (confidentialite = "Non"))
AND STR_TO_DATE(dateModification, '%c/%e/%Y %H:%i') BETWEEN '06/02/2012 11:55:09' AND '06/02/2012 19:55:09'
```

Also a possible shorter version of your code

```
SELECT idEcare,reference 
FROM DEMS
WHERE (((etatSuivant IN ("Etat_ADM_131276535415392&SURF=Transmis", "Etat_ADM_121276535415390&SURF=Traitement en cours", "Etat_ADM_11276535415374&SURF=A l étude", "Etat_ADM_81276535415384&SURF=Programmé")))
AND ((categorisation LIKE "%Propreté:Tas sauvage%") 
OR (categorisation LIKE "%Circulation et stationnement:Véhicule gênant%") 
OR (categorisation LIKE "%Circulation et stationnement:Véhicule ventouse_Epave_Brûlé%")
OR (categorisation LIKE "%Propreté:Passage ponctuel%") 
OR (categorisation LIKE "%Propreté:Corbeille pleine%") 
OR (categorisation LIKE "%Propreté:Huile_Verre cassé%") 
OR (categorisation LIKE "%Propreté:Désherbage_Feuilles mortes%") 
OR (categorisation LIKE "%Propreté%") 
OR (categorisation LIKE "%Espace Vert:Entretien des massifs:Nettoyage%") 
OR (categorisation LIKE "%Mobilier urbain:Corbeille:Réparation%")) 
AND (confidentialite = "Non"))
AND STR_TO_DATE(dateModification, '%c/%e/%Y %H:%i') BETWEEN '06/02/2012 11:55:09' AND '06/02/2012 19:55:09'
```

Comment: thaks for sharing ur time. I understand the STR_TO_DATE but i still have a format issue :

    AND STR_TO_DATE(dateModification, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i') BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND CURDATE()

Answer (score 1):

Seems OK

```
SELECT idEcare,reference 
FROM DEMS 
WHERE (((etatSuivant IN ("Etat_ADM_131276535415392&SURF=Transmis", ...
AND STR_TO_DATE(dateModification, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s") >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Thx Matt